# Fill empty value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing some empty values:

```
                 A            B             C
2000-06-28 -0,004990643  0,007052186    0,005671474
2000-06-29  0,025705329  0,024159664   -0,000350691
2000-06-30 -0,006723716 -0,006153846   -0,000142222
2000-07-03                             -0,001251731
2000-07-05 -0,056307692 0,002751978     0,000718968
2000-07-06 -0,022171503 -0,021269297    0,001399091
```

I would like to interpolate the missing values. How do I do this?

I tried using fillna but it seems that it's actually not n/a?

Comment: What would the interpolation be based on? For example, is the missing value in column A the average of the values directly above and below it?  or of all the values in column A?

Comment: Actually just found out it is NaN. but the fillNA still did not work? Interpolation can be the average of the values directly above and below.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert on this ... is this using pandas? If so, see if anything here helps http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html

Comment: Tried using: fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True) which seems to work, however I need to interpolate:
the page you linked suggested interpolate(method='linear') but this does not seem to work?

Comment: Tried using:  apply(pd.Series.interpolate(method='linear')) however I get the following error:  
TypeError: unbound method interpolate() must be called with Series instance as first argument (got nothing instead)